# Trouble displaying data from a database in TKinter

Tags: python, database, tkinter, sqlite

I'm creating a database in python using sqlite3 and tkinter. This is my first time doing something like this so I've been using examples on the internet to help build it. This has worked for the most part, however now I need to be able to display the data in the database in a table, and the example I've used doesn't seem to work properly for me. I've tried looking up other solutions, but nothing seems to help.

The problem is that when I go to open up the table, it doesn't get created. The program simply opens a new window and leaves it at that. There are no errors, so I don't know exactly what's wrong.

This is the entire code I've created so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

class Welcome():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('170x110+100+200')
        self.master.title('Welcome!')
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Test Database Main Menu',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text="Enter Data",fg='green',command=self.gotodataentry).grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.button2=Button(self.master,text="Data Records",fg='blue',command=self.gotorecords).grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.button3=Button(self.master,text="Exit",fg='red',command=self.exit).grid(row=3,column=1)

    def exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def gotodataentry(self):    
        root2=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI=DataEntry(root2)

    def gotorecords(self):
        root2=Toplevel(self.master)
        mygui=Records(root2)

class DataEntry():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('250x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Data Entry')

        self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Welcome to the data entry menu',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.label3=Label(self.master,text='Please enter some text',fg='black').grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.label4=Label(self.master,text='Please enter a number',fg='black').grid(row=4,column=0)

        self.text1=StringVar()
        self.text_entry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.text1).grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.int1=IntVar()
        self.int_entry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.int1).grid(row=4,column=1)
        self.button4=Button(self.master,text="Save",fg='red',command=lambda: self.savedata(self.text1.get(), self.int1.get())).grid(row=7,column=0)
        self.button5=Button(self.master,text="Exit",fg='red',command=self.exit).grid(row=9,column=0)

    def exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def savedata(self, text1, int1):
        con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Data (t1, i1) VALUES (?,?)', (text1, int1))
        con.commit()
        print('Record inserted in Data')

def Records(self):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('250x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Records')
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.textLabel = Label(self.master, text="Text", width=10)
        self.textLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.intLabel = Label(self.master, text="Number", width=10)
        self.intLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.showallrecords()

    def showallrecords(self):
        Data = self.readfromdatabase()
        for index, dat in enumerate(Data):
            Label(self.master, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
            Label(self.master, text=dat[1]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)

    def readfromdatabase(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Data")
        return self.cur.fetchall()

def main():
     root=Tk()
     myGUIWelcome=Welcome(root)
     root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

And this is the part I'm struggling with:

```
def Records(self):
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            self.master.geometry('250x200+100+200')
            self.master.title('Records')
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
            self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
            self.textLabel = Label(self.master, text="Text", width=10)
            self.textLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
            self.intLabel = Label(self.master, text="Number", width=10)
            self.intLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
            self.showallrecords()

        def showallrecords(self):
            Data = self.readfromdatabase()
            for index, dat in enumerate(Data):
                Label(self.master, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
                Label(self.master, text=dat[1]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)

        def readfromdatabase(self):
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Data")
            return self.cur.fetchall()
```

Could someone please help me figure out what's wrong? Sorry if the solution is incredibly simple, like I said this is my first time doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the solution is incredibly simple :D

Change

```
def Records(self):
```

To

```
class Records:
```

And the code works perfectly

Comment: No problem! (if you press the green tick it marks it as correct)